# from validator in angular returns strange value

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, validation, angular-forms

I have created a reactive form like the following which I fill it from the data gained from the server:

```js
newUserInfoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    personalInfo: this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [undefined, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('.*\\S+.*')]],
    }),
    legalInfo: this.formBuilder.group({
      companyName: [undefined, [Validators.required, Validators.required]],
    }),
  });
```

the problem is when I try to get the validation of the form, I get a strange behavior.
When I log the whole `this.newUserInfoForm.get('personalInfo').get('name')`, I see that the valid property is true, but when I log the `this.newUserInfoForm.get('personalInfo').get('name').valid` it is false. you can see this in the attached image as well

[image: logging both of them in the console]

as you can see the form is valid but in the first line when I log `this.newUserInfoForm.get('personalInfo').get('name').valid` it returns false

```js
checkFormValidation() {
    console.log(
      `this.newUserInfoForm.get('personalInfo').get('name').valid = ` + this.newUserInfoForm.get('personalInfo').get('name').valid
      // just to demonstrate properly I have added the string above
    );
    console.log(this.newUserInfoForm.get('personalInfo').get('name'));
    // this will return me the form which I have attached the photo of
  }
```

I will call this `checkFormValidation()` method after I subscribe data from the server and set value the form (for example setting "farBrand" as name)

so any solution to this?

Comment: it's just a timing issue. chrome's debugger shows the current state of a logged object, not the state when it was logged, but primitive values like booleans get logged as what they were when logged.  you're setting the value after you log the validity adn this is being reflected in the debugger

Comment: Is it possible to provide your code where you log the info to the console?
It seems the value is being set between the first and second log output but cant be sure without more info. 

What @bryan60 says is also true, when you log an object the properties and values will reflect the current state in chrome's debugger

Comment: I have edited the question for demonstrating how I log the data

Comment: I have changed the valid to value as "Aymen" told but it gives me null. If I use `.valid` instead of `.value`, I get false

Comment: and also I am logging all of that in the code and not in the chrome developers tool. it is function I want to check the validation of the form so I can disable a button

Comment: I understand that you are logging it in the code, what chrome debugger does however is when you expand an object after it was logged it will display the current state of the object and not the state at the time when it was logged. You can see this by checking the value property, it clearly has a valid value in the screenshot

Comment: so what is the solution? if I return the data and use it in my HTML for disabling a button, is it gonna work fine?

Comment: the timing issue is true, write it as an answer and I will accept that @Bart